# SQL:72025: The referenced assembly .DLL is corrupt or invalid

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Working with Visual Studio SSDT project, and am receiving an error when I compile the project on a new machine.

```
SQL:72025: The referenced assembly <path>.DLL is corrupt or invalid.
```

Compared project properties on original machine & new with no noticeable difference in configuration.  Cleared out the debug path as well as bin, cleaned solution, restarted VS, & rebuilt.  DLL is re-compiled and still shows error every time.  Do not have it configured as a reference, it is the DLL created during debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it with recreating project from the DB following the ms instruction and changing the project's folder.

Try first to change the project's folder. Actually still don't know what the problem with the folder.

As the second option try to create your DataBase Project exactly as described here [How to: Create a New Database Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/hh272677(v%3Dvs.103)).

Instruction:
To create a new database project off a connected database

1. Right-click the TradeDev node in SQL Server Object Explorer and
   select Create New Project.
2. In the Import Database dialog box, notice that the Source database
   connection settings have been predefined by the database you have
   selected in SQL Server Object Explorer. In the Target project
   setting, change the name of the project to TradeDev.
3. In the Import Settings section, notice the options for importing
   specific objects and settings, and creating folders for each schema
   and/or object type. For an organized hierarchy of all your database
   objects, accept all default settings and click Start.
4. The Import Database dialog shows a progress bar and displays a list
   of objects SSDT is importing. When the import operation has
   completed, click Finish to exit the final screen.
5. Examine the hierarchy in the Solution Explorer. Expand the dbo
   folder and you will find separate Functions, Tables and Views
   folders. Notice that the tables and function are grouped under their
   schema folders.
6. Double-click Products.sql under Tables. The Table Designer opens,
   showing the visual interpretation of the table in the Columns Grid,
   and the script definition of the table in the Script Pane. This is
   identical to what we see in the Connected Database Development
   section.
7. Uncheck the Allow Nulls box for the CustomerId column. Press CTRL +
   S to save the file.
8. Right-click the TradeDev project in Solution Explorer and select
   Build to build the database project.

The results of Build operation can be seen in the Output Window

If you haven't DB yet, just create the empty DB.

Comment: I'll give changing a folder a try. I can't use these steps for creating the database though because we're only copying one schema, not all of them. So I need to do compare, select the objects I need, and then update the project as the target.